# MongoParseError: Invalid connection string Express+Mongo

Tags: react, mongodb, rest, express.js, mongoose

Estou usando pela primeira vez o express e o mongo, ele funciona normalmente localmente, sem autenticação, mas quando passei para nuvem, na hospedagem da Umbler ele começou a apresentar erro

```
Jan 07 14:05:19   }
Jan 07 14:05:19   name: 'MongoParseError'
Jan 07 14:05:19   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30) {
Jan 07 14:05:19   at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/src/config/database.js:12:10)
Jan 07 14:05:19   at Mongoose.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:344:20)
Jan 07 14:05:19   at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1135:10)
Jan 07 14:05:19   at promiseOrCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
Jan 07 14:05:19   at new Promise (<anonymous>)
Jan 07 14:05:19   at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
Jan 07 14:05:19   at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:345:10
Jan 07 14:05:19   at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:817:19)
Jan 07 14:05:19   at new Promise (<anonymous>)
Jan 07 14:05:19   at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:820:12
Jan 07 14:05:19   at MongoClient.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:220:10)
Jan 07 14:05:19   at maybePromise (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:665:3)
Jan 07 14:05:19   at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:224:5
Jan 07 14:05:19   at connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:282:3)
Jan 07 14:05:19   at parseConnectionString (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:565:21)
Jan 07 14:05:19   MongoParseError: Invalid connection string
Jan 07 14:05:19   Listen in 3333
Jan 07 14:05:18   [nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
Jan 07 14:05:18   [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
Jan 07 14:05:18   [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
Jan 07 14:05:18   [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
Jan 07 14:05:18   [nodemon] 2.0.6
```

Meu database.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const url = 'mongo_todoappdb:27017'
const source = 'todoappdb'
const usr = '#########'
const pass = '########'
const db = 'todoappdb'

mongoose.connect(url, {
    authSource:source,
    user:usr,
    pass:pass,
    dbName:db ,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
    
})
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))    




    module.exports = mongoose;
```

Comment: voce esta tentando acessar uma base do mongo dentro do proprio umbler?

Comment: Isso mesmo,tô usando o link de prod deles

Comment: ao meu ver sua url deveria estar 'mongodb://mongo_todoappdb:27017' ao inves de só mongo_todoappdb:27017

Comment: Deu certo! não me atentei ao link kkk muito obrigado!